# Laravel Model Relations fetch automatically all other model relations too

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-relations

I'm hoping someone can help me.

I have 3 models like User, Task and Subtask.
These are already linked via hasOne or hasMany.
Everything works fine.
Now I call the data via Task::where(..)->with(['user','subtask'])... and get the corresponding results.

The problem is that Subtask has a reference to User and I don't get the user information queried when I use the task model.

If I use the subtask model I get the user information.

How can I set up that all references to the queried models are also queried simultaneously from the database?

Comment: Share your code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return more relationships data at once, you can use the following mechanism:

```
$Data = $Task::where(...)
    ->with([
        'user'=>function($userQuery){
            // mechanism is recursive; you can extend it to infinity :)
            $userQuery->with([
                            'other', 
                            'relationships', 
                            'here'=>function($hereQuery){ ... } 
                        ]); 
        },

        'subTask',

        'anotherRelationship' => function($anotherRelationship) {
            $anotherRelationship->select('column');
            $anotherRelationship->where('column2', 'whatever');
        }
    ])
    ->get();

// dump data
dd($Data);
```

---

I don't know if you're looking for this -- if you want to load some relationships once the model is instantiated, you can append a magic variable `$with` inside your model code and specify which relationships you want to load:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Task extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', ...];

    // specify which relationships you want to load automatically
    protected $with = [
        'users',
        'anotherRelationship'=>function($anotherRelationshipQuery){
            $anotherRelationshipQuery->select( ... );
        },
        'andSomeOtherRelationship'

        ...
    ];

    ...
}
```

Now you no longer need to manually load the relationships when retrieving data. They're loaded automatically:

```
$Data = $Tast::where( ... )->get();

dd($Data);
```

Comment: using the way with model and with method. Works fine. Thanks